# Irritation caused by Google-docs autosave notification blinking

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs

How can I disable auto-save notification (document status at the top of the screen) ? It always distracts me during typing even irritated by flickering . If you start to pay attention to that, the typing almost impossible. It is such a bad usability design IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notification is shown in an HTML element with class `docs-save-indicator-container`. This opens up several possibilities to disable/hide this element:

1. Use an ad-blocker like [uBlock](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/blob/master/README.md) and add a rule to block this particular element:

   ```
   ##.docs-save-indicator-container
   ```
2. You can use a custom stylesheet manager like [Stylus](https://add0n.com/stylus.html) and add a rule like this:

   ```
   .docs-save-indicator-container {
     display: none;
   }
   ```

Comment: Ohh I thought, there is something built-in Google-docs, but yeah I think I will use the trick. Thanks!